# Relative date filter on calendar week not calculating last date of the latest week correctly

Tags: powerbi

I have date dimension table and sales fact table.

Created a chart visual with date week on x axis and values as sum of salesamt.

In the filter pane added relative filter to the date. In the last 4 calendar weeks.

I have a measure that shows LASTDATE(DateTable[Date]) also on the report.

The last date is showing as 6 Feb 2021 (Saturday)

Same value when I select the latest week on x axis.

However when I choose any prior week on x axis, then the last date value is Sunday 31 Jan 2021.

Why does the current week last date show as 6th Jan 2021 (saturday) instead of 7th Jan 2021 (sunday)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, calendar week is defined Sunday to Saturday when it comes to filtering using relative dates. You can work around it by introducing additional column (basically `date - 1 day`) and set your relative filter on that.